# How to fix "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Tags: python

I am using keras to generate the images of dogs using GAN for a kaggle competitions. I am using google colab. But i am encountering an error.

**ERROR**

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

**CODE**

Here is the function:

```
def load_data():
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = load_data()
x_train = (x_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5)/127.5
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
return (x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)
(X_train, y_train,X_test, y_test)=load_data()
print(X_train.shape)
```

Hope anyone can help.

Comment: You're calling `load_data` inside `load_data` twice on the second and second last lines. That will go on forever. What's your intent there? Did you accidentally call this function the same name as another function?

Answer (score 1):

The function is doing infinite recursion, its called `load_data()` and it calls `load_data()` without any recursion limit, hence infinite recursion.

You probably want to call `load_data()` in a module, like `cifar10` or `mnist`, and for that you have to specifically refer to that module, for example, `keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()`.

Comment: Ok thank u. But what if i want to load _data through custom dataset?